# Reload controllers after scope change (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, routes, scope

so
I have this controller for swapping languages

```
app.controller("langCtrl",['$scope','$route',function($scope,$route){
    this.swap_lang = function(){
        if(lang == "tr"){
            lang = "en";
        }else{
            lang = "tr";
        }
        console.log(lang);
        this.lang = lang;
        //$route.reload();
        //$scope.$apply();
    };
}]);
```

And this one below *is supposed to be* responsible for bringing up menus (*JSON files with short language codes*) according to the **global variable language** outside Angular

```
var lang = "en";
app.controller("menusCtrl",['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){
    $scope.test = lang;//for testing
    var these_menu =  this;
    these_menu.links = [];
    these_menu.titles = "";
    $http.get("menu-" + lang + ".json").success(function(data){
        these_menu.links = data[0].menus;
        console.log("Menus are here!");
        console.log(these_menu.links[2].sub_menus[1]);

    });
}
```

The lang variable swaps, but the **menusCtrl** is not refreshed ! :(

how can i update the views with the new data , how can i make my controllers reload views with new data , I've tried **reload** and **apply** but no luck

> PS : The **console prints** short language codes after clicking from
>   view

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) You can declare json file, then swap language with $translate.use(key); and the rest is automagicly updated !

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , I will consider using it in future apps , but i wanted a simple solution for this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would break this into a service for your $http uses throughout your app. Like so:

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

demo.service('GetData', function() {
  this.returnJsonByLangType = function(lang) {
    /** 
    *  normally I would use a function like 
    *  this to do the http work:
    *
    *  var response = $http.getJson(lang+'/dir/file.json');
    * Instead this will just alert the value with each change, 
    * ...you get the idea
    *
    **/

    alert('Current lang is: '+lang);

    // return response;

  }
});

 // Then I would instantiate a new service call returning the json based on the scope value which is changed via user selection of a link in the case below:

demo.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope, GetData) {
  $scope.languages = ['english', 'spanish', 'french'];
  $scope.activeLangSelection = $scope.languages[0]; // Default
  $scope.setLang = function(lang) {
    $scope.activeLangSelection = GetData.returnJsonByLangType(lang);
  };
});
```

PS: Your meaning of 'this' is not pointing to $scope where it should be maintainig all data from your controller... maybe want to look at that too.

Heres the pen but $http will not work unless I had the API code which returns the data based on the lang, but this should get you where you need to be http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/Qbgrzv.

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't handle external variable very well. Set your lang variable as a value provider instead :

```
app.value("lang","en");
```

Then you better define a factory to handle language swapping like so :

```
app.factory("langFactory",['$scope','$route', 'lang', function($scope, $route, lang){
    this.swap_lang = function(){
        lang == 'tr' ? 'en' : 'tr';
        console.log("lang",lang);
        $scope.$digest;
    };

    this.lang = function(){
        return lang;
    };

    return this;
}]);
```

and then use it like that and add a watch on test variable to update in case of change

```
app.controller("menusCtrl",['$http', '$scope', 'langFactory', function($http, $scope, langFactory){
    $scope.test = langFactory.lang;//for testing
    var these_menu =  this;
    these_menu.links = [];
    these_menu.titles = "";

    $scope.$watch("test",function(lang){
        $http.get("menu-" + lang + ".json")
            .success(function(data){
                these_menu.links = data[0].menus;
                console.log("Menus are here!");
                console.log(these_menu.links[2].sub_menus[1]);
            });
    });

}
```

Comment: It brings up this one https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20langFactory